# play japid Why can't we use variable parameters

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, extends, japid

```
@String idBase="[sys]/prmode/add";
@String htmlName="addDept";
@Strig title="add";
@extends japidviews.web.bk._main.html(title,htmlName,idBase)
```

Japid Compilation Error
japidviews/web/bk/prmode/addDept.java(68): The field _main.title is not visible

```
public cn.bran.japid.template.RenderResult render() {

67      long __t = -1;

68      try {super.layout(title,htmlName,idBase);} catch (RuntimeException e) {    super.handleException(e);} 

69      return new cn.bran.japid.template.RenderResultPartial(getHeaders(), getOut(), __t, actionRunners, sourceTemplate);

70  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `Strig title` instead of `String title`.